# How do I get invite-request notification?

Tags: notifications, request, invite

I have a problem :) I will be thankful if anyone could help me.
I have approved game, but there is a problem with invite requests from friends - they are not seen in notifications http://prntscr.com/8u026n and notification beeper is not coming also http://prntscr.com/8u02ns 
But I can see all invites in activities.
Invite request is made like here:

> [developers.facebook.com/docs/games/invitable-friends/v2.5](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/invitable-friends/v2.5)

What should I do to see invite requests in notifications and also receive notification beeper? =) 
Thank you! :)